# Having issue with Chrome inlcuding styles on Print Preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code works all fine on Firefox Mozilla, but not in Chrome or IE:

```
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
```

The message in console is:

> [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML
>   Imports is deprecated

Thou if I do it like this it works for all browsers:

```
printWindow.document.write('<style>body {background:red}</style>');
```

Any idea how would I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I fully understand your issue but I did put the following [Pen](https://codepen.io/DanStevens/pen/Lgvvpr) together as an example of how I'd solve this. As you can see I was able to use an external css library in the new window. Tested in Chrome 70 and Edge, but I don't have a reliable way to test in IE.

You can disregard the portion of javascript that pulls in content from the original window, I just assumed that was functionality you would be using.

```
var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=400,height=400");
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitterbootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
```

Comment: can u also show the print preview at the same time? printWindow.print(); I guess when u add this it will not work!

Comment: I've updated the Pen to include .print() after a slight delay. While this works in Chrome I'd recommend looking into using print specific [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) instead of a new window, but i'll admit I don't have all the details around your issue.

Comment: the styling does not seep to apply after the print executed

Comment: It seems that it fixed this for me :), Can you please explain why having this timeout  is needed to work in this case , will also accept your answer :)

Comment: It appears that the .print() method runs before the new window is fully rendered. Using the onload method would likely be a better solution, but I believe Chrome (and probably others) have restrictions around automating the print() method without a user's interaction. Here's a link to more detail for the onload method:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp